# How do I handle default settings in XML Serialization/Deserialization?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

My attempt to create default settings isn't working out, when I deserialize the object from XML file, I get repeating entries that aren't supposed to be there.  But the first time i write to XML I get the correct number

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ConfigurationData a = Config.GetConfigData();

            ConfigurationData c = new ConfigurationData();
            Config.SaveConfigData(c);
        }
    }


    public static class Config
    {
        #region Default Data

        public static List<ProductType> PRODType = new List<ProductType>();

        private static ProductType PRODType1;
        private static ProductType PRODType2;

        // name of the .xml file
        private static string CONFIG_FNAME = "config.xml";

        public static void GetDefaultConfig()
        {

            PRODType1 = new ProductType();
            PRODType1.PRODType = "P1";
            PRODType1.Item = new ProductItem();
            PRODType1.Item.Name = "product1";
            PRODType1.Item.Path = @"\test\test";

            PRODType2 = new ProductType();
            PRODType2.PRODType = "P2";

            PRODType.Add(PRODType1);
            PRODType.Add(PRODType2);

        }

        #endregion



        public static ConfigurationData GetConfigData()
        {
            if (!File.Exists(CONFIG_FNAME)) // create config file with default values
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(CONFIG_FNAME, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ConfigurationData));
                    ConfigurationData sxml = new ConfigurationData();
                    xs.Serialize(fs, sxml);
                    return sxml;
                }
            }
            else // read configuration from file
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(CONFIG_FNAME, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ConfigurationData));
                    ConfigurationData sc = (ConfigurationData)xs.Deserialize(fs);
                    return sc;
                }
            }
        }

        public static bool SaveConfigData(ConfigurationData config)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(CONFIG_FNAME)) return false; // don't do anything if file doesn't exist

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(CONFIG_FNAME, FileMode.Open))
            {
                XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ConfigurationData));
                xs.Serialize(fs, config);
                return true;
            }
        }


    }

    // this class holds configuration data
    public class ConfigurationData
    {
        public List<ProductType> ProductTypes;

        public ConfigurationData()
        {
            Config.GetDefaultConfig();
            ProductTypes = Config.PRODType;
        }
    }


    public class ProductType
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Value")]
        public string PRODType { get; set; }

        public ProductItem Item { get; set; }
    }


    public class ProductItem
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("Path")]
        public string Path { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("Attribute")]
        public string Attribute { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of the ConfigurationManager library that will read XML files and look for specific tags such as "appSettings" and easily allow you to read and write from them.

Create your XML that is structured as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <configSections>
   </configSections>

   <appSettings>
      <add key="ClientId" value="5017" />
      <add key="LocationCode" value="01"/>
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then you can read and write with code (example in WinForms app) such as:

```
MyConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration _
                                         (ConfigurationUserLevel.None)

MyConfig.AppSettings.Settings("ClientId").Value = txtClientId.Text
MyConfig.AppSettings.Settings("LocationCode").Value = txtLocation.Text
MyConfig.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings")
```

I outlined how you can do this easily [here](http://dillieodigital.wordpress.com/2009/10/02/simple-global-editable-application-settings-in-winforms-applications/).

Comment: I remember why I wanted my own xml file, it was because I'm building a class library and I need to bundle the configuration with the DLL.  Is there a way to do this with configurationManager?

Comment: I believe the ConfigurationManager constructor will allow you to specify a file name to open. As long as you have the file structured as outlined above, you should be just fine, regardless of the name.